# ...params not working in my Reach Component

Tags: reactjs, components, react-router

Trying to create a Nav component however in my code base "...params" cause an "unexpected token" error:

```
render() {
  const {router} = this.context;
  const {
    index,
    onlyActiveOnIndex,
    to,
    children,
    ...params
  } = this.props;
  const isActive = router.isActive(to, onlyActiveOnIndex);
  const LinkComponent = index
    ? Link
    : IndexLink;
  return (
    <li className={isActive
      ? 'active'
      : ''}>
      <LinkComponent {...params}>{children}</LinkComponent>
    </li>
  );
}
```

The error displayed:

> ERROR in ./src/components/common/NavItem.js
>   Module build failed: SyntaxError: 
>   C:/Development/varAssignPages/src/components/common/NavItem.js: 
>   Unexpected token (16:6)

Comment: In your title it says `...props`, in your question `...params`, which one is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spread inside the JSX tag, but there's no need to use it when creating the `const`. Try this:

```jsx
const {
    index,
    onlyActiveOnIndex,
    to,
    children,
    params
  } = this.props;

// ...

<LinkComponent {...params}>{children}</LinkComponent>
```

Comment: Fabian that did it, I didn't catch until seeing it in your code base. Thanks man I appreciate the help.